# make ChoiceMenu default selection working in evince and Master PDF Editor

Tags: hyperref, evince

If you open a pdf in evince where a ChoiceMenu is available (see code below), then all the choices are selected. If you open the same pdf with Master PDF Editor, then all choices are unselected. How can I set the default selected choice to true and everything else to false? It should work with evince and Master PDF Editor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% make ChoiceMenu unselect work
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \makeatletter
        \patchcmd{\HyField@FlagsRadioButton}{\HyField@SetFlag{Ff}{Radio}}{}{}{}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \mbox{\ChoiceMenu[width=10pt,height=10pt,name=choiceMenuName,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{ =yes}} Yes
        
        \mbox{\ChoiceMenu[width=10pt,height=10pt,name=choiceMenuName,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{ =no}} No
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

code result in evince:
[image: code result in evince]
code result in Master PDF Editor:
[image: code result in Master PDF Editor]

Answer (score 1):

You can try if it works better if you set the value and default key explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% make ChoiceMenu unselect work
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \makeatletter
        \patchcmd{\HyField@FlagsRadioButton}{\HyField@SetFlag{Ff}{Radio}}{}{}{}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \mbox{\ChoiceMenu[width=10pt,height=10pt,value=yes,default=yes,name=choiceMenuName,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{ =yes}} Yes

        \mbox{\ChoiceMenu[width=10pt,height=10pt,value=no,default=yes,name=choiceMenuName,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{ =no}} No
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

But imho the radio buttons are not correctly implemented in hyperref.
Radio buttons belonging to the same group should have a common field as parent.

There is a new implementation of radio buttons which tries to do it correctly. It requires a very new LaTeX and the newest `pdfmanagement-testphase`. Be aware that this experimental code and not yet compatible with everything.

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3pdffield-testphase}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdffield_radio:n{group=A,value=button1,default=button1}~YES\par\smallskip
\pdffield_radio:n{group=A,value=button2}~NO\par
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Output with adobe (I don't have evince or your other pdf editor).

[image]

Comment: Thank god someone is finally admitting that it is not correctly implemented. I previously only read comments, that the implementation of all pdf readers are not correct, except for Adobe Reader. When can I expect the l3pdffield-testphase solution to be widespread? I am using [latexonline.cc](https://latexonline.cc/) to compile my documents for my website visitors. How do I set up my system (debian with Tex Live) to be able to test the testphase packages?

Comment: your system use texlive 2020, that is not new enough. you could try with texlive.net instead https://texlive.net/, that is always up-to-date. And regarding the implementation: the code is quite old, and it is both unclear how exactly the specification was at the time it was written, and how pdf viewer behaved.

Comment: So the solution with the testphase packages works fine for Master PDF Editor, but not with evince. Evince is not showing the radio buttons but if you hover, then the mouse changes so you know that there is something clickable. Is it possible to change the form of the radio buttons like in my example with mbox and ding?

Comment: the appearances can be changed, but if evince doesn't like the default one, it probably won't like variants. What happens if you load hyperref *before* the testphase package and add \Form to the document?

Comment: About the testphase packages solution: After flattening the form fields with Master PDF Editor, the radio buttons also disappear. So the solution does not seam to be 100% compatible with Master PDF Editor.

Comment: well form field support is sketchy across the viewers, and infos what the various viewers support (and how they react to the various options) is not really available. The documentations of the fields are here https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfmanagement-testphase, l3pdffield.pdf and l3pdffield-radiobutton.pdf. Basically every option from the pdf specification is setable.

Comment: If I usepackage hyperref and make Form around the ExplSyntax then nothing changes. Same behavior as before.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that I am happy enough with is to not use ChoiceMenu and instead use CheckBox:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \mbox{\CheckBox[checked=true,width=10pt,height=10pt,name=choiceMenuNameYes,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{}} Yes
        
        \mbox{\CheckBox[checked=false,width=10pt,height=10pt,name=choiceMenuNameNo,radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52}]{}{}} No
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

output in evince:

[image: output in evince]

output in Master PDF Editor:

[image]

I am not content about this solution so this is not the final answer to the question.