Radio buttons created using hyperref can't be read out in Python
I am using hyperref to create a fillable PDF form. Then, I attempt to use a Python script to read out form values. While it is possible to read out values from e.g. text fields, the radiobutton values do not change from '/\\Fld@default '. I don't know for certain whether the issue is in my document or in the Python script, but I suspect the former.
Document
MWE, based on another SE question:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        {Do you want to: }%
        \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{Do it all again=Again}
        \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{Pretend it never happened=Pretend}
        \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{Write a book about it=Write}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}

Script
from collections import OrderedDict
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfReader
from pprint import pprint

def _getFields(obj, tree=None, retval=None, fileobj=None):
    """
    Extracts field data if this PDF contains interactive form fields.
    The *tree* and *retval* parameters are for recursive use.

    :param fileobj: A file object (usually a text file) to write
        a report to on all interactive form fields found.
    :return: A dictionary where each key is a field name, and each
        value is a :class:`Field<PyPDF2.generic.Field>` object. By
        default, the mapping name is used for keys.
    :rtype: dict, or ``None`` if form data could not be located.
    """
    fieldAttributes = {'/FT': 'Field Type', '/Parent': 'Parent', '/T': 'Field Name', '/TU': 'Alternate Field Name',
                       '/TM': 'Mapping Name', '/Ff': 'Field Flags', '/V': 'Value', '/DV': 'Default Value'}
    if retval is None:
        retval = OrderedDict()
        catalog = obj.trailer["/Root"]
        # get the AcroForm tree
        if "/AcroForm" in catalog:
            tree = catalog["/AcroForm"]
        else:
            return None
    if tree is None:
        return retval

    obj._check_kids(tree, retval, fileobj)
    for attr in fieldAttributes:
        if attr in tree:
            # Tree is a field
            obj._build_field(tree, retval, fileobj, fieldAttributes)
            break

    if "/Fields" in tree:
        fields = tree["/Fields"]
        for f in fields:
            field = f.get_object()
            obj._build_field(field, retval, fileobj, fieldAttributes)

    return retval


def get_form_fields(infile):
    infile = PdfReader(open(infile, 'rb'))
    fields = _getFields(infile)
    return OrderedDict((k, v.get('/V', '')) for k, v in fields.items())

pdf_file_name = './read_pdf_form/mwe.pdf'
pprint(get_form_fields(pdf_file_name))


the radio button implementation is buggy, see https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/3 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/602124/2388. If you use the default key explicitly it will probably more or less work but generally I would recommend to use the new l3pdffield-testphase code (the documentation for radio buttons is in l3pdffield-radiobutton.pdf).

@UlrikeFischer Thanks, with a lot of trial and error, I was able to recreate my form using l3pdffield! I will answer my own question.

Based on the comment of @UlrikeFischer, I have indeed been able to solve this using l3pdfffield, which I now use for my form. For future reference:
\DocumentMetadata{pdfversion=2.0}

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{l3pdffield-testphase}
\usepackage{tabularray} % Tables with convenient vertical centering
\begin{document}
    Do you want to:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 
        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \pdffield_radio:n{group=MyGroupOfRadiobuttons,value=Again}
        \ExplSyntaxOff
        Do it all again
        
        \item 
        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \pdffield_radio:n{group=MyGroupOfRadiobuttons,value=Pretend}
        \ExplSyntaxOff
        Pretend it never happened
        
        \item 
        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \pdffield_radio:n{group=MyGroupOfRadiobuttons,value=Write}
        \ExplSyntaxOff
        Write a book about it
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{document}

If using code like mine to read out the radiobutton values, an additional change is needed to map the value index to the actual value:
def get_form_fields(infile):
    infile = PdfReader(open(infile, 'rb'))
    fields = _getFields(infile)

    # Replace radiobutton values, from index to corresponding text value
    for key in fields:
        if '/Opt' in fields[key] and fields[key]['/V'][0] == '/': # Check whether field has array of options, and whether current value starts with '/'
            i = int(fields[key]['/V'][1]) # Get value index
            fields[key][PyPDF2.generic.NameObject("/V")] = PyPDF2.generic.TextStringObject(fields[key]['/Opt'][i]) # Set actual value, cast to PyPDF2 types

    return OrderedDict((k, v.get('/V','')) for k, v in fields.items())


In a current LaTeX the two first lines should be replaced by \DocumentMetadata, and don't use uncompress for normal documents, that is for debugging (it produces uncompressed PDF). (I know that I often forget to remove the option when showing examples, sorry for that.)  The pdffield code produces a bit larger PDF as it uses appearances everywhere, but it shouldn't be dramatically different to the hyperref code.

@UlrikeFischer You are entirely right, and I have updated the example. Thank you for the explanation!
