Make radio field checkboxes without border inside a box drawn by tikz in PDF forms
I found helpful code on a blog (https://www.maltegerken.de/blog/2021/07/creating-pdf-forms-with-latex/) which helped me a lot in the attempt to make a form. But there is one thing I'm not able to write myself.
The author built radio field (choice) checkboxes inside a box drawn by tikz as many PDF viewers I tested place the checkboxes themselves without a border.

This helps a lot and looks nice. However, the author only wrote a fix solution for Yes-No-Choices. I'd like to have a new command, let's say "radiobox" where the "\ChoiceMenu"-command can still be used in a form-environment to build choice groups freely for different purposes, but to have the same layout with the box drawn by tikz. Is there somebody able to adapt the style and provide a solution? I wasn't ...
This is the code to build the Yes-No-Choice (seen at https://www.maltegerken.de/blog/2021/07/creating-pdf-forms-with-latex/):
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pbox}

\renewcommand*{\DefaultOptionsofRadio}{print,radio, radiosymbol=6, width=\baselineskip, bordercolor={black}, borderwidth=0pt}

\newcommand{\radiosize}{0.33cm}
\newcommand{\yesnoticks}[1]{%
\raisebox{-3.2pt}{\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]
  \node[anchor=west,style={inner sep=2px}] (FieldYes) at (0cm,0cm) {\ChoiceMenu[radio=true,name=#1,width=\radiosize,height=\radiosize]{}{=Yes}};
  \node[anchor=west] (LabelYes) at ([xshift=0.7ex]FieldYes.east) {Yes};
  \node[anchor=west,style={inner sep=2px}] (FieldNo) at ([xshift=1ex]LabelYes.east) {\ChoiceMenu[radio=true,name=#1,width=\radiosize,height=\radiosize]{}{=No}};
  \node[anchor=west] (LabelNo) at ([xshift=0.7ex]FieldNo.east) {No};
  \draw [thick] ([xshift=-(\radiosize+0.15cm),yshift=-(\radiosize+0.15cm)]FieldYes.north east) rectangle (FieldYes.north east);
  \draw [thick] ([xshift=-(\radiosize+0.15cm),yshift=-(\radiosize+0.15cm)]FieldNo.north east) rectangle (FieldNo.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
}
\newcommand{\yesno}[2]{\pbox{0.7\textwidth}{\setstretch{1}#1}\hfill\yesnoticks{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \yesno{I like Pets}{pets}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}


you should always show a complete example and not only some snippet. That makes testing easier. Apart from this: the radio button code in hyperref is not so good, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/718463/2388

I added code so that it's a full document.
